# Why is element pushing outside the bounds fixed div?

Tags: html, css

In my app I have a fixed footer, inside this I want an input text box on the left and a button on the right.

The `html` and `LESS` I have is:

```css
.button {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #1f628d 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#totalPoints {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 20px 0.5em 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

input {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="totalPoints">
  <input type="text" value.two-way="totalPoints" readonly>
  <button class="button">Test</button>
</div>
```

[image: Sticky footer]

> I am expecting the button on the right to be within the confines of the div, but it is pushing outside the div.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

The margin for #totalPoints make it go out of bounds...

```
#totalPoints {
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 0px 0px 0px; 
        background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct here. Setting Margin to 0 should help fix the problem :)

Comment: @simonzhu and what if the OP want to keep the use of margin ? :) this solution will make the button and the field to be stacked on the border and i think the OP want some margin on left and right ;) .. Also why removing the bottom margin ? it's only the left that causing the issue. So this is not THE solution but one solution as the op need to understand the issue is not only margin ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif +1 Valid and important points to note. Thanks for bringing them up. You are right :)

Comment: Well, it was a fast reply and I had to post it before someone else beat me to it... :P Of course, the other margin values need not be touched and hopefully he plays with the margin values before getting the optimum one!

Comment: `before someone else beat me to it` : it's not a battle :) it's better to take time and provide a well explained answer then doing it fast .. the purpose is to provide answer for the OP and futur comer and make StackOverflow a good ressource for everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the issue at first glance, so copied your code to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4yjnu9L9/.

```
<div id="totalPoints">
      <input type="text" value.two-way="totalPoints" readonly>
      <button class="button">Test</button>
</div>

.button {
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: solid #1f628d 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#totalPoints {
        position:fixed;
        left:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 20px 0.5em 20px; 
        background:#fff;

        input {
            width: 30%;
            float: left;
        }

        .button {
            float: right;
        }
    }
```

In fiddle, it seems that the button does appear within confines of the div. My guess is that there is some CSS (possibly JS) that overrides the position attribute for your button causing it to be positioned outside the div.

Perhaps you can open web console and take a look at the position / display / float attributes actually applied to the button?

I am happy to follow up if you can provide additional info :)

Edit:

Seems like I might have been mistaken.
Like @TemaniAfif mentioned in his solution, margin with width 100% set is pushing the alignment out of the viewport. Possible solutions are either set margin to 0 or set width to only a smaller percentage.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am writing this answer to try to help Vinyl solve this problem. Of course I cannot be 100% sure because I cannot see all his code. So I am providing educated guess :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with only **margin**. It's also because you specified a width of **100%** and when adding margin your element `#totalPoints` will take more space than the viewport and thus pushed outside by the amount of **margin-left**. So exactly 20px will be hidden from this element which make the button (right floating inside it) to be hidden.

To fix this and keep the use of margin, remove `width:100%` and replace it with `right:0` or replace margin with padding and add `box-sizing:border-box`.

```css
.button {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #1f628d 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#totalPoints {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  right:0;
  margin: 0 20px 0.5em 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
#totalPoints-alt {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 100px; /*Increased the bottom to see both solution*/
  height: 60px;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding: 0 20px 0.5em 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

input {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- Solution with right:0  -->
<div id="totalPoints">
  <input type="text" value.two-way="totalPoints" readonly>
  <button class="button">Test</button>
</div>

<!-- Solution with padding  -->
<div id="totalPoints-alt">
  <input type="text" value.two-way="totalPoints" readonly>
  <button class="button">Test</button>
</div>
```